# The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: PUT. Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem with save-aboutus page.  I am pretty new to Laravel, I don't know how can I fix this.
**I get this error:**

> The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods:
> PUT.

**routes(web.php):**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth','admin']], function() {

  Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
      return view('admin.dashboard');
  });

  Route::get('/role-register',[App\Http\Controllers\Admin\DashboardController::class, 'registered']);
  Route::get('/role-edit/{id}',[App\Http\Controllers\Admin\DashboardController::class, 'registeredit']);
  Route::put('/role-register-update/{id}',[App\Http\Controllers\Admin\DashboardController::class, 'registerupdate']);
  Route::delete('/role-delete/{id}',[App\Http\Controllers\Admin\DashboardController::class, 'registerdelete']);
  Route::get('/abouts',[App\Http\Controllers\Admin\AboutusController::class, 'index']);
  Route::post('/save-aboutus', [App\Http\Controllers\Admin\AboutusController::class, 'store']);

});
```

**Controller:**

```
class AboutusController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
      return view('admin.aboutus');
    }

    public function store(Request $request){
      $aboutus = new Abouts;

      $aboutus->$title = $request->input('title');
      $aboutus->$subtitle = $request->input('subtitle');
      $aboutus->$descreption = $request->input('description');

      $aboutus->save();
      return redirect('/abouts')->with('success','Success');
    }
}
```

**and blade.php**

```
<form action="/save-aboutus" method="POST">
        {{ csrf_field() }}

        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Title:</label>
            <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" id="recipient-name">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="message-text" class="col-form-label">Sub-title</label>
            <input type="text" name="subtitle" class="form-control" id="recipient-name">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="message-text" class="col-form-label">Description</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" name="description" id="message-text"></textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
</form>
```

[image]

Comment: can you show more of the error message? what URL is currently showing in your address bar?

Comment: not the code in the stacktrace the actual error message at the top ... but what URL is currently showing in your address bar? and I imagine this is happening after submitting that form?

Comment: @lagbox no, I didn't use javascript

Comment: what URL is in your address bar currently?

Comment: @lagbox 127.0.0.1:8000/save-aboutus

Comment: seems it is hitting a different route and with the wrong method (by the error) ... how are you submitting this form?

Answer (score -1):

You just need to add a GET route if you want to access it with GET method:

```php
  Route::get('/save-aboutus', /* handler */);
```